# Personalize PageRank initial scores in jGraphT

Tags: java, pagerank, jgrapht

I have a question regarding the implementation of PageRank in Java using the jGraphT library.

I need to personalize the initial scores that PageRank gives to nodes. Instead of the usual 1/n, I need to use other values. These values will still make the adjacency matrix stochastic (i.e. a row sums up to 1), so that there is no problem with the convergence criterion.

In the [docs of jGraphT](https://jgrapht.org/javadoc-1.3.1/index.html?org/jgrapht/alg/scoring/PageRank.html), I see that there are only two methods in the PageRank class, namely `getScores` and `getVertexScore`. Is there a way to personalize PageRank initial scores or import the adjancency matrix that PageRank will use?

I found [their code base](https://github.com/jgrapht/jgrapht/blob/master/jgrapht-core/src/main/java/org/jgrapht/alg/scoring/PageRank.java) on Github, so I can still download it and change the code by myslef ; but if I can find a nicer way to do it, it would be better.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to do what I want by downloading the code base and changing the adjacency matrix as needed.

I'm closing my post.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).